# In the design time data does not display

Tags: windows-phone-7, data-binding, mvvm

I am developing application in silverlight for WP7. I decided to use MVVM pattern. I hove class ViewModelLocator, which locates ViewModels. More in example:

```
public sealed class ViewModelLocator
{

    private static ViewModelLocator _instance = null;        
    public static ViewModelLocator Instance
    {
        get 
        {
            return _instance;
        }
        set
        {
            _instance = value;                                        
        }
    }

    public SomeViewModel SomeVM
    {
        get
        {
              ........
        }
    }
........
}
```

DataContext is adjusted by binding to Instance.SomeVM, Locator is an instance of ViewModelLocator.

```
DataContext="{Binding Instance.SomeVM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

I have problem with projection of  Data in the View during design time when I am binding DataContext to the Instance.LocationDetail.

When I made minor changes and then I set DataContext only to SomeVM.. data are displayed.

Why does not data display in the design time, when I use Binging to Instance.SomeVM ?

In the runtime everything works fine. In both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When do you initialize the Instance property?

I assume you have added an instance of ViewModelLocator in the resources of your app with the key 'Locator', but even like this it seems that the property Instance will stay null because it's never assigned.

If you do:

```
DataContext="{Binding Instance.SomeVM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

You try to get the value of SomeVM from the property Instance. But Instance is probably null...

This should work:

```
DataContext="{Binding SomeVM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

And if you want a singleton pattern, you should consider initializing your Instance property:

```
private static ViewModelLocator _instance = null;        
public static ViewModelLocator Instance
{
    get 
    {
        if(_instance == null)
            _instance = new ViewModelLocator();
        return _instance;
    }
    set
    {
        _instance = value;                                        
    }
}
```